# Monads and comonads from monoids

Tags: category-theory

Given a symmetric monoidal closed category $\mathscr{C}$, and a monoid $M\in\mathscr{C}$,
is a functor $(-) \otimes M:\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}$ a monad? I think the unit and the multiplication are naturally obtained from the monoid structure of $M$.

Moreover, is a functor $[M, -]$ a comonad? I think the definition of the counit and the comultiplication involve Yoneda's lemma.

Comment: Have you tried to define your morphisms $\mu:F^2\to F$, $\eta:\mathrm{id}_{\mathscr C}\to F$ and check the monad conditions?
Have you tried doing the other part with $[M,-]$?

Comment: Yes, and I think the monad conditions are immediate from the monoid conditions. But the comonad conditions are difficult to check because the definitions of morphisms $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ involves Yoneda's lemma, and I got stuck.

Comment: I figured out that the monad part was a "writer monad" https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+monad.

Comment: I don't see how the comonad axioms should be harder to verify. The construction $[-, -]$ is contravariantly functorial and strongly monoidal in the first variable. It immediately follows that it sends a monoid in the first variable to a comonoid in the category of endofunctors, i.e. a comonad.

Comment: how is it going?